# before hook in rspec same as before :all?

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am wondering whether the `before` (as seen below) is the same as `before :all` in RSpec. Sometimes neither `:each` nor `:all` is specified and it confuses me as to what `before` actually does.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "this is a description" do 
  before do # vs. before :all or before :each
   # do something...
  end
end
```

Would appreciate if anyone can explain the differences, if any. Thanks!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

So the answer is No. `before` is equivalent to `before :each`, not `before :all`

[Test example](https://gist.github.com/3494874).

**Update**: Wow, this question is popular. To save your head from cognitive overload, I suggest you explicitly state `:each` or `:all`.

Comment: I want to add that if you nest before contexts without specific runtime like before(:each) it will NOT override the upper level before hooks. You can then nest hooks and add code to the pile but be careful as this could cause you problems.

Comment: I bet this is particularly popular because the rspec doc page for before doesn't mention the default. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks